# how to add hook in object creation process in .net

Tags: .net, hook

I want to customize a object's behavior before the object is created. I think maybe add some hooks in the object constructor and do the change there would be a choice. Is there any way to  do so in .net? Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here is a example:

Assume we have a class Kid which use Perform method to get credit in the class.

```
public class Kid
{
    public void Perform() { ... }
}
```

And the School conduct to lectures:

```
public class School
{
    public void Chemistry() {
        // The school have a good chemistry teacher, so every kid study well
        // Kid.Perform() is modified to reflect that 
        Kid tom = new Kid();
        tom.Perform();
    }

    public void Biology() {
        //This class is boring, everyone will nap in 5~10 min
        // Kid.Perform() use a random number to simulate how 
        //long this kid can hold it.
        Kid tom = new Kid(); tom.Perform();
        Kid jerry = new Kid(); jerry.Perform();
    }
}
```

We want every kid perform in the same way and I do not want:

1. Change class Kid because it is generated from a 3rd party tool and widely used somewhere else.
2. Use inheritance.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you mean by customising object behaviour? If you mean instantiating the same class various times with some particular behavioural difference, then perhaps passing a delegate in as a constructor parameter is an option?

Comment: I'm modifying legacy code, and I want to specify how object will be created. After that, all object creation will follow that rule.

Comment: What do you mean by "how the object will be created?"  Can you not change the code in the class' constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you would have to add your logic after calling the constructor. You could write a factory method which does this; replacing `new SpecialObject()` with `MyExtendedSpecialObject.Create()` shouldn't be too difficult.

```
public static class MyExtendedSpecialObject
{
    public static SpecialObject Create()
    {
        var newObject = new SpecialObject();

        // Do something with newObject

        return newObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, lots of people use factory method. But I'm modifying legacy code. and an "injection" way is preferred.

Comment: @Roy: A simple search and replace shouldn't be too difficult. AFAIK such injection as you want isn't possible (except perhaps through something like aspect-oriented programming?).

Answer (score 0):

You would simply add logic to the object's constructor.  If you are referring to the process of hooking into the allocation of memory etc then that's not available in .NET.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        // Constructor logic here...
    }

    public MyClass(string name)
    {
         // Overloaded constructor logic here...
    }
}
```

Comment: The object is generated by a 3rd party tool. Wrap the class can solve my problem but means lots of refactoring works which I'm not so satisfied. Is there anyway else? Thanks!

Comment: Well, along the same vain you can use an extension method to provide an `Initialize` method, but this would be functionally similar to wrapping it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Activator to create the instances. You can also 'hook' into the activator and perform your checks.

Comment: this will not work, the the asker is not in control of the creation code, otherwise he could just use his own factory.